# What is the fastest key type for the dictionaries in python? tuple, frozenset...?

Tags: python, sorting, data-structures, cluster-analysis, k-means

Context: I am trying to speed up the execution time of k-means. For that, I pre-compute the means before the k-means execution. These means are stored in a dictionary called means_dict which has as a key a sequence of the points id ordered in ascending order and then joining by an underscore ,and as a value the mean of these points. 
When I want to access to the mean of a given points set in dict_mean dictionary during the k-means execution, I have to generate the key of that points set ie order the id points in ascending order and joining them by an underscore.
The key generation instruction takes a long time because I the key may contain thousands of integers.

I have for each key a sequence of integers separated by an underscore "-" in a dictionary. I have to sort the sequence of integers before joining them by an underscore in order to make the key unique, I finaly obtain a string key. The problem is this process is so long. I want to use an another type of key that permits to avoid sorting the sequence and that key type should be faster than the string type in terms of access, comparison and search.

```
 # means_dict is the dictionary containing as a key a string (sequence of 
 # integers joined by underscore "-", for example key="3-76-45-78-344")
 # points is a dictionary containing for each value a list of integers
 for k in keys:
     # this joining instruction is so long       
     key = "_".join([ str(c) for c in sorted(points[k])])        
     if( key in means_dict ):
         newmu.append( means_dict[key] )
```

Comment: Can you give us a bit more context? What are you trying to accomplish? Why are the dictionary keys for means_dict in the given way when the points are given as a list of integers?

Comment: @IonicSolutions I added the context, see the question please.   Points is a list of points id of a set or class. The dictionary means_dict has k:v format, v is the mean of the set represented by the string key k.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question! I'm only vaguely familiar with the k-means algorithm, but I doubt that pre-computing the mean of all possible sets of points will speed up the algorithm. If I understand the algorithm correctly, initially k random sets of points are chosen and then altered, so for most possible sets of points the mean will never need to be computed. Have you checked that pre-computing computes fewer means than the original k-means? Since your question aims at improving an implementation detail of a potential improvement: Have you tried improving your means() method?

Comment: In general, the answer to "which is faster" questions is "try it yourself and see." In your case, I would suggest you try `frozenset`, as it doesn't require sorting (by you--I don't know whether it sorts internally).

Comment: @IonicSolutions  I pre-compute only means those have a big chance to be used by k-means. I use Voronoi to get the k sets in order to pre-compute means. I saw that some pre-computed means are used by k-means. When I compare the execution time of my k-means with standar k-means I saw that my k-means is a little worse because of the long time of key generation in means() method.means with standar k-means I saw that my k-means is a little worse because of the long time of key generation in means() method.

Comment: Have you tried optimizing the method used to compute the mean? If this computation is what slows down your k-means algorithm, this would be the first place to look for ways to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the means is cheap.

**Did you profile your program?** How much of the time is spent recomputing he means? With proper numpy arrays instead of python boxed arrays, this should be extremely cheap - definitely cheaper than constructing *any* such key!

The reason why computing the key is expensive is simple: it means constructing an object of varying size. And based on your description, it seems you will be building first a list of boxed integers, then a tuple of boxes integers, then serialize this into a string and then copy the string again to append the underscore. There is no way this is going to be faster than the simple - vectorizable - aggregation when computing the actual mean...

You could even use MacQueens approach to *update* means rather than recomputing them. But even that is often slower than recomputing them.

I wouldn't be surprised if your approach ends up being 10x slower than regular k-means... And probably 1000x slower than the clever kmeans algorithms such as Hartigan and Wong's.